# Partition listed as read-only but isn't!

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, read-only

I have a 2GB external drive which it appears Nautilus thinks is read-only; but it isn't! Basically I cannot add files and folders by right-clicking.

I have tried restarting and it doesn't help. I can open a terminal and go to the folder and it works fine to use the mkdir command (without sudo) and I am also the owner. Right-clicking shows that I am the owner of the folder and that I have read/write access to folders. I can save documents from gedit to it, for example.

Using Ubuntu 12.04. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add the output of `mount` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this bug a few days ago and didn't find any solution for it. There is only some [official confirmation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375) on Launchpad.

But then I came across a patched version of Nautilus from the SoluOS project, and so installed it in the few easy steps [described here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-solusos-patched-nautilus-in-ubuntu-1204.html).

And now Nautilus works OK.